# Excel match multiple records from timetable

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I just stuck with my school homework, it seems easy, but there is always different errors and mistakes.

**Context**

All I need is to connect information from 3 pages.

- The first one is timetable of trainings.
- The second page is "groups"
- Players page

**Question**

1) Here is my first question. How I can put the time from the "timetable" page ?

I tried vlookup with the easiest group "children 5-7" but even this doesnt work.

The problem is that there is many possible times of some groups and I need the answer like "17:00, 18:00 etc" then.

2) The second question is with the page "players".

Firstly I need to match group or coach from page "groups". For children all is simple, but excel dont want to work even with this. But, there is one problem more. In adult group there cant be more than 4 players in one group, that why I have TK1, TK2, TK3 and TK4 - all this are for adult A. and TK11, TK22 etc are for adult B. So when its done we should match court and time from page "groups".

There is my spreadsheet so be free to try it right here. Hope you will help me!

**Ref**
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PNp60xmHOx_Q1wBc33WrzIaWmeNG5UMhi-4roV7dJXU/edit#gid=1868650910

Comment: i've done some stuff at your sheet... however... there lots of problems you should at least try to solve... having more than one match, you need a some rule for the answer you are looking for...

Comment: groups and players should now work as wanted...

Comment: Have you looked into Index/Match? It's similar to Vlookup, but you can use multiple values to search.  If you want to post some sample data, and how it's laid out, we can try to get a formula going (I hesitate to download files from the web, especially if macros are  involved).

Answer (score 1):

I try to give you some ideas about how to solve your issues

**Question 1:**

The issue you have with VLOOKUP is that you cannot search on the left of your lookup value in the reference table. As suggested above by BruceWayne, you may use INDEX/MATCH. Considering the structure of your data a good formula could be:

```
=INDEX('timetable try here'!B:G,MATCH(A2,CHOOSE(B2,'timetable try here'!C:C,'timetable try here'!D:D,'timetable try here'!E:E,'timetable try here'!F:F,'timetable try here'!G:G),0),1)
```

In fact I am using CHOOSE() to select the column where your case should match, because your courts are numbers from 1 to 5. You may replace this formula in the column D under the label Time in your sheet named "groups try here". By the way the result that you get is only the first occurrence (in case you see a zero with some decimals figures, remind to change format to hours), so you will not be able to get the list as you like. As far as I know Excel does not have such kind of formulas. What you could do is create a VBA formula by yourself. You can find more details in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973561/comparing-and-counting-values/33982773#33982773) always here in StackOverflow, where I replied to a similar question with some code. I believe that your case is exactly the same.

**Question 2**

In this part I just added the last argument to the VLOOKUP and your formula works. So the correct formula should be in cell E2 of "players try here":

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,'groups dont try here'!A2:C15,3,0)
```

and in cell F2 (Court) of the same sheet:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,'groups dont try here'!A2:C15,2,0)
```

I believe you need also a formula to pick-up the time in cell G2 (time):

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,'groups dont try here'!A2:D15,4,0)
```

These formulas of course works with suitable groups starting with "children". For the others it is not very clear to me what you need. If you have grouped all TK in Adult A and Adult B you need to have some criteria to fill in the other cells from your sheet 'groups dont try here'. Also remind that if you recode the TK1 and TK2 (for instance by adding a new column to be used as key for the VLOOKUP), with VLOOKUP you will always pick up only the first occurrence in the table.

If you need more support, please leave a comment.